# Parse-platform verifyPassword method

Tags: parse-platform

what's going on with verifyPassword method? When I look into code Parse.User doesn't have verifyPassword method but i documentation i can see this http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.15.0/Parse.User.html#.verifyPassword

Comment: The method is over there: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/ParseUser.js#L811

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which worked for me in Node.js:

```
try {
    await Parse.User.verifyPassword(params.username, params.password.toString(),{useMasterKey:true});
} catch (error) {
    throw new Parse.Error('Invalid current password. Try again');
}
```

Comment: Since what version of Parse Server is it available?

Comment: Hi @SotirisKaniras,
I'm currently using "parse": "^3.3.1" & "parse-server": "~4.10.3". The thing is verifyPassword is not defined in Parse types. If that makes sense.